# Node / method-override giving error on PUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am experiencing an issue using method-override and attempting to use it to PUT to an item in Mongo. So I can make the call through Postman and have the document update as expected but when attempting to do so from through the UI we receive:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/characters/?_method=PUT
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Here is the routes and such:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
//
// 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

routes

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
      Character.findOne({
        _id: req.params.id
      })
     .then(character => {
     //
     //
     character
     .save()
     .then(character => {
       res.redirect('/characters/show/${character.id}');
     })
});
```

and the HTML

```
  <form action="/characters/{{character.id}}?_method=PUT" method="POST" class="col s12">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn">
  </form>
```

Thanks all, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should this be `router.put('/characters/:id` or is this router already attached to a Router with prefix `/characters`?

Comment: Either way the requested route doesn't exist in the code - the `:id` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing in a value for `:id` in the route, and you don't have a route for just `/characters/`.

> `URL:http://localhost:3000/characters/?_method=PUT`

You need to make sure that `character.id` is set - it seems to be empty in your example.

> `action="/characters/{{character.id}}?_method=PUT"`

You are also specifying `POST` as the method for the form, you should use `PUT`.

> `method="PUT"`

If you want to make the `:id` parameter optional follow it with a question mark:

> `router.put('/:id?', (req, res) => {`

You can also test the route by hard coding a value and see if you still get a 404.

> `action="/characters/123?_method=PUT"`

Comment: The OP is using the `method-override` middleware, so the `method="POST"` on the form should work fine.